# Free Php encoder

Tags: php

I dont know whether this is correct posting place, can anybody please suggest me few free php encoding softwares as i dont have any money to buy one currently?

FOR ENCODING PHP SCRIPTS / SOURCE CODE

Thank You.

Comment: Encoding... What exactly? Video? Audio? Text?

Comment: Maybe in this special case a none open-source software fits better to your needs - you can take a look at e.g. [www.codecanyon.net](https://codecanyon.net/search/php%20encoder) and search for `php encoder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Free PHP encoder](http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Web_Authoring/Scripting_Tools/PHP_Encoder.html) (?)

> The PHP Encoder allows to encode PHP
>   scripts before distributing it.

What encoder are you looking for?